# HTML: Select - 2 different text color inside an Option

Tags: html, css, select

Is there a way to do this?, inside my Database i have some Color names and their color codes in the same row, so by server side languaje im putting the color name inside the option but also i need to add a little circle ascii character that should be styled with the color code.

Here is a simple example without PHP and all the stuff i mentioned, just to show the logic i tried till now.

```
 <select>
   <option style="color: black;"><span style="color: red;">●</span>RED</option>
   <option style="color: black;"><span style="color: blue;">●</span>BLUE</option>
   <option style="color: black;"><span style="color: green;">●</span>GREEN</option>
   <option style="color: black;"><span style="color: yellow;">●</span>YELLOW</option>
 </select>
```

Here is an image, on the left is how it looks, on the right is how i would like it. Notice that is not the same select here above:
http://s18.postimg.org/o88wtqv1l/dqwdqwdqwdqwd.jpg

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will helpful

```
<select>
 <option style="color: red;">●RED</option>
 <option style="color: blue;">●BLUE</option>
 <option style="color: green;">●GREEN</option>
 <option style="color: yellow;">●YELLOW</option>
</select>
```

and check using this link http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/

Comment: That will make the option text and the ● the same color and that is not what i want. All the texts (RED, BLUE, GREEn AND YELLOW) have to be black, and only the spot ● should be in color.